# How to do a select query using multiple roots with Criteria Builder

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, predicate, criteria-api

I'm extremely new to using criteria builder so this is my first go at it. I'm trying to use multiple entity classes so I'm using multiple roots to compare with stuff. I feel like my select statement near the end of the first method is wrong because I'm not incorporating both of the roots into it. Especially since I'm using sl and sld to compare stuff in the predicates where clause. Do I need to join them somehow? How would I go about adding more classes in the future? Would I have to change the select statement if I wanted to pick specific things from each table to return into a custom object? Thanks.

Pulled select statement:

```
cq.select(sl);
cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
```

Full Class:

```
@Repository
public class DealerTotalsQueryRepository {

    private static final String START_DATE = "0001-01-01";
    private static final String TERMINATION_DATE = "terminationDate";
    private static final String KEY = "key";
    private static final String DEALER_CODE = "dealerCode";
    private static final String SERVICE_LETTER_NUMBER = "serviceLetterNumber";
    private static final String OPEN_COMPLETE_IND_O = "O";
    private static final String OPEN_COMPLETE_IND_C = "C";
    private static final String COMPLETION_DATE = "completionDate";
    private static final String TERM_IND_NTERM = "nterm";
    private static final String TERM_IND_TERM = "term";
    private static final String SERVICE_LETTER_DATE = "serviceLetterDate";

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public List < ServiceLetter > findAllServiceLetters(Map < String, String > searchCriteriaData) {

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery < ServiceLetter > cq = cb.createQuery(ServiceLetter.class);

        Root < ServiceLetter > sl = cq.from(ServiceLetter.class);
        Root < ServiceLetterDesc > sld = cq.from(ServiceLetterDesc.class);

        List < Predicate > predicates = new ArrayList < > ();

        String marketOrg = searchCriteriaData.get(GlobalConstants.MARKET_ORG);
        String dealerCd = searchCriteriaData.get(GlobalConstants.DEALER_CD);
        String programNo = searchCriteriaData.get(GlobalConstants.PROGRAM_NO);
        String openCompleteInd = searchCriteriaData.get(GlobalConstants.OPEN_COMPLETE_IND);
        String termInd = searchCriteriaData.get(GlobalConstants.TERM_IND);
        String dateFrom = searchCriteriaData.get(GlobalConstants.DATE_FROM);
        String dateTo = searchCriteriaData.get(GlobalConstants.DATE_TO);
        String pinPrefix = searchCriteriaData.get(GlobalConstants.SERIAL_NO_PREFIX);
        String letterType = searchCriteriaData.get(GlobalConstants.LETTER_TYPE);
        java.sql.Date currentDate = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        if (marketOrg != null && !marketOrg.isEmpty()) {
            //predicates.add(cb.equal(sl.get(""), ""));
        }
        if (dealerCd != null && !dealerCd.isEmpty()) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(sl.get(KEY).get(DEALER_CODE), dealerCd));
        }
        if (programNo != null && !programNo.isEmpty()) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(sl.get(KEY).get(SERVICE_LETTER_NUMBER), programNo));
        } else {
            predicates.add(pipPspIndCodeClause(cb, sld, letterType));
        }

        if (openCompleteInd != null && !openCompleteInd.equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
            if (openCompleteInd.equalsIgnoreCase(OPEN_COMPLETE_IND_O)) {
                predicates.add(cb.equal(sl.get(COMPLETION_DATE), START_DATE));
            } else if (openCompleteInd.equalsIgnoreCase(OPEN_COMPLETE_IND_C)) {
                predicates.add(cb.notEqual(sl.get(COMPLETION_DATE), START_DATE));
            }
        }
        if (termInd != null && !termInd.equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
            if (termInd.equalsIgnoreCase(TERM_IND_NTERM)) {
                Predicate termEToStart = cb.equal(sld.get(TERMINATION_DATE), START_DATE);
                Predicate termGTCurrentDate = cb.greaterThan(sld.get(TERMINATION_DATE), currentDate);
                predicates.add(cb.or(termEToStart, termGTCurrentDate));
            } else if (termInd.equalsIgnoreCase(TERM_IND_TERM)) {
                Predicate termGTStartDate = cb.greaterThan(sld.get(TERMINATION_DATE), START_DATE);
                Predicate termLTOETCurrentDate = cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(sld.get(TERMINATION_DATE), currentDate);
                predicates.add(cb.and(termGTStartDate, termLTOETCurrentDate));
            }
        }
        if (dateFrom != null && !dateFrom.isEmpty()) {
            predicates.add(cb.between(sld.get(SERVICE_LETTER_DATE), dateFrom, dateTo));
        }
        if (pinPrefix != null && pinPrefix.isEmpty()) {
            /*          buff.append("AND A.SER_NO_PFX IN (" + setupWhereIn(pv, parms.get(ChooseQuery.PIN_PREFIX_KEY), true, 3) + ") "); */

        }
        cq.select(sl);
        cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));

        TypedQuery < ServiceLetter > q = em.createQuery(cq);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    private Predicate pipPspIndCodeClause(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root < ServiceLetterDesc > sld, String letterType) {

        Predicate pipPspIndCode = null;
        Predicate predTemp1 = null;
        Predicate predTemp2 = null;
        Predicate predTemp3 = null;
        Predicate predTemp4 = null;

        List < String > serviceLetterNumberList = Arrays.asList(new String[] {
            "956151",
            "956170"
        });
        Expression < String > serviceLetterNumberExpression = sld.get(SERVICE_LETTER_NUMBER);

        if (letterType != null && !letterType.equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
            switch (letterType) {
                case "pip":
                    pipPspIndCode = cb.like(sld.get(SERVICE_LETTER_NUMBER), "94%");
                    break;
                case "pipsaf":
                    predTemp1 = cb.like(sld.get(SERVICE_LETTER_NUMBER), "940%");
                    predTemp2 = cb.like(sld.get(SERVICE_LETTER_NUMBER), "941%");
                    pipPspIndCode = cb.or(predTemp1, predTemp2);
                    break;
                case "pippri":
                    pipPspIndCode = cb.like(sld.get(SERVICE_LETTER_NUMBER), "943%");
                    break;
                case "psp":
                    pipPspIndCode = cb.like(sld.get(SERVICE_LETTER_NUMBER), "95%");
                    break;
                case "pspbaf":
                    predTemp1 = cb.like(sld.get(SERVICE_LETTER_NUMBER), "954%");
                    predTemp2 = cb.like(sld.get(SERVICE_LETTER_NUMBER), "958%");
                    predTemp3 = cb.or(predTemp1, predTemp2);

                    predTemp4 = cb.between(sld.get(SERVICE_LETTER_NUMBER), "9590016", "9590109");
                    pipPspIndCode = cb.or(predTemp3, predTemp4);
                    break;
                case "pspaf":
                    predTemp1 = cb.like(sld.get(SERVICE_LETTER_NUMBER), "955%");
                    predTemp2 = cb.between(sld.get(SERVICE_LETTER_NUMBER), "9560000", "9560027");
                    predTemp3 = cb.or(predTemp1, predTemp2);

                    predTemp4 = serviceLetterNumberExpression.in(serviceLetterNumberList);
                    pipPspIndCode = cb.or(predTemp3, predTemp4);

                    //predTemp4 = cb.in(sld.get(SERVICE_LETTER_NUMBER)).value(serviceLetterNumberList);
                    break;
                case "pspcn9":
                    pipPspIndCode = cb.between(sld.get(SERVICE_LETTER_NUMBER), "9590110", "9599999");
                    break;
                case "pspcn6":
                    predTemp1 = cb.between(sld.get(SERVICE_LETTER_NUMBER), "9590110", "9599999");
                    predTemp2 = serviceLetterNumberExpression.in(serviceLetterNumberList).not();
                    pipPspIndCode = cb.or(predTemp1, predTemp2);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return pipPspIndCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: root is always only 1. That is why it is root....

Comment: @Antoniossss Okay, then how would I pull information from a second class?

Comment: using joins (there is join and joinFetch), just as you would do it in SQL

Comment: Alright, still a bit new to this. Could you provide a decent source to look at?

Comment: Google is full of it. Just google "criteria api fetch join"

Comment: @Antoniossss I was looking and in this page, it says you can have more than 1 root. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html Am I just interpreting this wrong? Or? (It's about part way down under "QUERY ROOTS")

Comment: hard to say as example shows that you have 2 instances of the same root... all in all JOINS should do the trick for you.

Comment: Nah, one is ServiceLetter and one is ServiceLetterDesc. But definitely looking into the joins. Thank you.

Comment: The issue I'm having now is nested objects and whatnot, oh well.

Comment: No, I meant that example in the link you provided have 2 instances of the same root.

Comment: Nested objects-> you mean related objecst i hope -> joins